# How to make Python release memory back to OS?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to configure python runtime to be more eager on releasing memory back to the OS. Is that possible?
In Java for a comparison it is possible to set the configuration MaxHeapFreeRatio, if the percent of free space in a generation grows over the MaxHeapFreeRatio then the JVM release memory to the OS to keep the ratio of free memory allocated by the JVM under the configured ratio. Is there anything like this in Python?

Comment: No. Python's garbage collection is based on reference counting. Python will free memory whenever an object's reference counter goes down to zero. Whether this goes back to OS depends on the underlying allocator (you may want to try jemalloc with Python). Also Python does reuse some small pieces of memory (e.g. cached integers) but you don't have control over that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, reference counting is one way Python GC uses to collect memory but it also uses the Generational garbage collection, which accounts to detect reference cycles. You can read about it here  https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/
My question is not about how memory is collected is about how memory is released back to the OS.

Comment: Define what does "how memory is released back to the OS" means. Python uses `calloc` or `malloc` which *does not* release memory to the OS *most of the time*. On Linux, releasing memory would mean [munmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html) which `malloc` and `free` try hard to avoid calling

Comment: @Rogerthat "It is important to understand that the management of the Python heap is performed by the interpreter itself and that the user has no control over it," https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html So from your perspective it doesn't matter "how". You have no control over it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Every process running on a OS allocate memory, uses it, and when it does not need it anymore it releases it back to the OS, right? As you said Python does not 'usually' releases memory back, because it is expensive to get it back later if needed, but in some cases it does release, I am interested in understanding when it does release memory to the OS, and if I can influence it.

Comment: Read a [textbook on *Operating System*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) then **study the [source code of Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/)**, since it is [open-source software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software). See also http://linuxatemyram.com/

Comment: @freakish, I do understand that, I just want to make sure that there is no way known to do it, as per Java, which has a similar memory management allows it with the MaxHeapFreeRatio.